# I spilled something on my rk61 keyboard and now it types an extra word. How can I fix this?

Tags: keyboard

I spilled something on my rk61 keyboard. Now, most of the time when I type c it adds a /, and when I type / it adds a c. Is there any way to fix this?
Edit: now the whole zxcvbnm,./ row does this

Comment: Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: You can get a keyboard at Nordic Keyboards, eBay. Takes about a week. I got an X230 keyboard from them and that fixed my machine.